# viewing image in picturebox using listview in vb.net 2008

Tags: vb.net

I am working in vb.net 2008 with listview control. I added some images in listview.items using imagelist. now I want to show that image in picture box when I clicked on button. I had tried some time for this but getting error everytime.

Here is the code :

```
Public Class Form1
  Private Sub ListView1_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles ListView1.MouseClick

    PictureBox1.Image = Bitmap.FromFile(ListView1.Items.Item(1).ToString)

  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: May be add the actuall error message? Or should we guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the picture to show when you click a button then I think you want to use Button_Click instead of ListView_Click

```
Private Sub MyButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyButton.Click      
     'Also, might be easier just to do this:
     PictureBox1.Image = ImageList1.Images(0)

End Sub
```

Then you can set different buttons for your different pictures